# “Service: Service is required.” - Unable to create jira service desk project issue

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a Jira service desk project issue using v2 rest API. I am passing all mandatory fields value but Jira throwing below error.

responseStatusCode : 400

```
{
    "errorMessages": [
        "Service: Service is required."
    ],
    "errors": {}
}
```

Sharing the data below,

Data sent to create the service desk incident,

```
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "GSD"
    },
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Incident"
    },
    "customfield_10402": "test",
    "customfield_12608": {
      "id": "15300"
    },
    "summary": "Test Ticket Please ignore - Jira Testing",
    "description": "this is description"
  }
}
```

where the **customfield_10402** is a *string* field and the **customfield_12608** is a *dropdown* field.

**Project details :**

```
"projectCategory": {
            "self": "https://domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10400",
            "id": "10400",
            "name": "Service Desks",
            "description": "Customer facing service desk containers, sitting behind single support portal site"
        },
        "projectTypeKey": "service_desk",
        "simplified": false,
        "style": "classic",
        "isPrivate": false,
        "properties": {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the request structure above is used to create a Jira issue.

What you are looking for is creating a service desk request.

Jira Service Desk creation should look like this EXAMPLE

```
{
    "serviceDeskId": "10",
    "requestTypeId": "25",
    "requestFieldValues": {
        "summary": "Request JSD help via REST",
        "description": "I need a new mouse for my Mac"
    },
    "requestParticipants": [
        "john"
    ]
}
```

Please find more info here 
[JIRA Service Desk REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/3.6.2/#servicedeskapi/request-createCustomerRequest)